# datetime returns a datetime.date() instead of just the date inside a dictionary

Tags: python, datetime

If I `print(final_date)` I get the return I am looking for `2022-02-26`. However not printing it and just calling it I get an undesirable return `{'date': datetime.date(2022, 2, 26)}`. But in order to return it in a dictionary, I have to call it because if I try to print it I will get `None`:

```
number_of_days = 5
final_date = datetime.today().date() - timedelta(days=int(number_of_days))
print(final_date)

job = {
    'date': print(final_date)
}

print(job)
```

and if I just call it I get the undesirable result.

```
number_of_days = 5
final_date = datetime.today().date() - timedelta(days=int(number_of_days))
print(final_date)

job = {
    'date': final_date
}

print(job)
```

How can I get the desirable reuslt within a dictionary.

Edit:
How can I get the desired return from date from the following code

```
number_of_days = 5
final_date = datetime.today().date() - timedelta(days=int(number_of_days))
final_date1 = print(final_date)
print(final_date)

joblist = []

job = {
    'date': final_date,
    'career': 'arborist',
    'salary': 65000
}

joblist.append(job)

print(joblist)
```

Comment: When you print a dictionary, it prints the `repr()` of the values, not `str()`. It's the same data, just being printed differently. Use `print(job['date'])`

Comment: Thank you that did help me, however I realize I broke the problem down too much and the real issue is the one I have edited, since its not just a dictionary but a list of dictionaries and I still would like the final date to be formatted to the desirable result.

Comment: `for job in joblist: print(job['date'])`

Comment: Why do you care about this? You shouldn't be printing the entire list as part of the application. Use formatting functions to produce the desired output. `print(joblist)` should only be for debugging, not the user interface.

Comment: I am just trying to get the desired output tested in a dictionary before I put it in mysql database, and in the mysql database I only want the desired output

Comment: When you put it into the database, it doesn't use `print()`, so how is that relevant? Are you planning on putting `str(joblist)` in the database?

Comment: I was gonna put final_date in the database but i am gonna be unable to get the desired result unless i print it

Comment: Use `datetime.strfrtime()` to format a date.